# How to Make Random Path

Tags: algorithm, path, logic

I want to create totally random path using cube.
I'll give Source value and a number of tiles and the terminal will be random and an algorithm will return a list of location.

There are difficulty level and path should be created as difficulty.

Currently, I have been creating path but how can I manage difficulty level?

Exmaple of paths:

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far? Can we see the code?

Comment: What is defined as "more difficult" or "less difficult"? If you're referring to the number of "turns" in the path, or maybe the ratio between the number of turns and the length, that could be one way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe draw some inspiration from [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166124/448932) to another question.